# Permutations with repetition element condition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I'm trying to figure out:

How many permutations (with repetition allowed) does A,B,C have for a given $k$ (the length of the permutation) if A cannot be followed by a C anywhere in the end result?

AAABC, ABC, BBBBBC, ABABABC, CCCAB are valid but

AC, CAC, BAC, ACB, ABABAC are not valid

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way would be by recursion. Let's write

$ N(k) = \# \{ \text{valid sequences of length k} \} \\
N_A(k) = \# \{ \text{valid sequences of length k, ending with an A} \} $

Let's think about, how to get the number of valid sequences of length $ k+1 $, starting from sequences of length $ k $. At the end of every sequence we can always add an $ A $ or a $ B $. However, we can only add a $ C $, if the sequence is not ending with an $ A $. There are $ N(k) - N_A(k) $ sequences, which end with an $ A $. So togheter we see

$ N(k+1) = 2N(k) + (N(k) - N_A(k)) = 3 N(k) - N_A(k) $

We can express $ N_A(k) $ even easier: how do we get any sequence of length $ k $, ending with an $ A $? Well, we can put an $ A $ at the end of every sequence of length $ k-1 $, so

$ N_A(k) = N(k-1) $

We can put that into the upper formula to get

$ N(k+1) = 3 N(k) - N(k-1) $

Now we have a recursion formula, which we can use to compute the number of valid sequences. To get a direct formula, you can try to solve the recursion formula, for which I'm not an expert. But I think you could do it by solving it using linear algebra. Observe that

$ \begin{pmatrix} N(k+1) \\ N(k) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} N(k) \\ N(k-1) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^k \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $

Now you could compute a direct forula by solving the eigenvalue problem of the corresponding matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with:

If $r_{k}$ denotes the number of such permutions that end with $A$
and $s_{k}$ denotes the number of such permutions that do not end
with $A$ then to be found is $r_k+s_k$ where:

$r_{k+1}=r_{k}+s_{k}$

$s_{k+1}=r_{k}+2s_{k}$